# Scanner to TextIO question

Tags: java.util.scanner

I need to add a value and input it directly into an array using TextIO.
I know that if I was using Scanner I would use the in.nextDouble() function, but how would I do it using TextIO?

```
 TextIO.put("Enter credit hours:");
 creditHour[sem][grd]+=in.nextDouble(); //I have to use TextIO here.
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

array [i][r] = TextIO.getlnDouble();